# Optional argument to spawn

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm trying to spawn a process with an argument that may (or not) be present. My actual code looks like this:

```
set optionalParam ""

if { somecondition } {
    set optionalParam someValue
}

spawn foo.sh paramA paramB "param C" $optionalParam
```

The problem happens when `somecondition` is false. `foo.sh` sees an additional parameter, with empty value (like `""`).

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got Tcl 8.5 or later, you *definitely* should use an expanding substitution:

```
set optionalParam [list]
if { somecondition } {
    lappend optionalParam someValue
}

spawn foo.sh paramA paramB "param C" {*}$optionalParam
```

---

In 8.4 and before, you were instead forced to use something like this:

```
set optionalParam [list]
if { somecondition } {
    lappend optionalParam someValue
}

eval [list spawn foo.sh paramA paramB "param C"] $optionalParam
```

This was decidedly error prone and long-winded and many Tclers tended to use shortcuts like

```
set optionalParam ""
if { somecondition } {
    set optionalParam someValue
}
eval spawn foo.sh paramA paramB paramC $optionalParam
```

This would fail “interestingly” with `"param C"` though. Or if the real `someValue` has a space in it. (Try working out why for yourself! Consider yourself to have a bonus point if you can do it without using a Tcl interpreter to do it for you.) It was because of these troubles that we added the expansion syntax in Tcl 8.5, which is *hugely* easier to get right.

Comment: I remember the fights over the exact syntax though; it was a good thing we were doing it over email at the time (around 10 years ago) or we might've come to violence with each other. It was way worse than the fights over adding OO support in 8.6…

Comment: If my problem was a bit more complex, I'd stick to your suggestions, but since it's a pretty simple use case, the simple list expansion worked well (using escaped quotes for inner spaced strings, of course). Anyway, thanks for the answer and the funny comment :)

ps: any downside on the "simple expansion" approach?

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple correct ways to do it.  Personally, I'd put all the params into a list, then expand the list at the end:

```
set params {paramA paramB "param C"}
if { somecondition } {
    lappend params someValue
}
spawn foo.sh {*}$params
```

You could do the same thing with a string if you prefer.

Comment: I figured exactly this solution by myself, but I'm accepting Donal's answer as it's more complete. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: No problem.  He almost always has superb answers; my only hope is to get in before he does. :)